# How to render data horizontally in table ( react )?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am junior developer and I am facing issue ( react ) when I want to render data  horizontally in table.
Is there I way to render data in columns not rows, using `<table>` not `<div>` wthout nesting errors in console? The only solution I came up with is to map every row (very bad solution).

Here is table I want to make:

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyFIs.jpg

My code sample:

```
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        {meals.map((meal) => (
          <td>DAY {meal.id}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>6:00AM</th>
        {meals.map((meal) => (
          <td>{meal.sixAM}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>9:00AM</th>
        {meals.map((meal) => (
          <td>{meal.nineAM}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>12:00AM</th>
        {meals.map((meal) => (
          <td>{meal.twelveAM}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3:00PM</th>
        {meals.map((meal) => (
          <td>{meal.threePM}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>6:00PM</th>
        {meals.map((meal) => (
          <td>{meal.sixPM}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <p>Workout</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
};
```

I am fetching data from db.json.
Data:

````
{
  "meals": [
    {
      "id": 64,
      "sixAM": "Bod•ē Shake",
      "nineAM": "Ham and Swiss Roll Ups",
      "twelveAM": "Turkey Melt",
      "threePM": "Bod•ē Burn with Mozzarella and Tomato Slices",
      "sixPM": "Turkey Melt",
      "Carb": "LOW-CARB"
    },
    {
      "id": 65,
      "sixAM": "Bod•ē Shake",
      "nineAM": "Ham and Swiss Roll Ups",
      "twelveAM": "Turkey Melt",
      "threePM": "Bod•ē Burn with Mozzarella and Tomato Slices",
      "sixPM": "Turkey Melt",
      "Carb": "LOW-CARB"
    },
    {
      "id": 66,
      "sixAM": "Bod•ē Shake",
      "nineAM": "Grilled Steak (HC)",
      "twelveAM": "Bod•ē Shake",
      "threePM": "Bod•ē Burn and Whole-Wheat English Muffin with Butter Spray",
      "sixPM": "Garlic Lime Chicken (HC)",
      "Carb": "HIGH-CARB"
    },
    {
      "id": 67,
      "sixAM": "Bod•ē Shake",
      "nineAM": "Ham and Swiss Roll Ups",
      "twelveAM": "Turkey Melt",
      "threePM": "Bod•ē Burn with Mozzarella and Tomato Slices",
      "sixPM": "Turkey Melt",
      "Carb": "LOW-CARB"
    },
    {
      "id": 68,
      "sixAM": "Bod•ē Shake",
      "nineAM": "Ham and Swiss Roll Ups",
      "twelveAM": "Turkey Melt",
      "threePM": "Bod•ē Burn with Mozzarella and Tomato Slices",
      "sixPM": "Turkey Melt",
      "Carb": "LOW-CARB"
    },
    {
      "id": 69,
      "sixAM": "Bod•ē Shake",
      "nineAM": "Ham and Swiss Roll Ups",
      "twelveAM": "Turkey Melt",
      "threePM": "Bod•ē Burn with Mozzarella and Tomato Slices",
      "sixPM": "Turkey Melt",
      "Carb": "HIGH-CARB"
    },
    {
      "id": 70
    }
  ]
}```
````

Comment: There is an example on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headers)

Comment: @bigBadWolf, check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
  renderMealTable(meals) {
    const mealTimes = {
      sixAM: '6:00 AM',
      nineAM: '9:00 AM',
      // .. all meal times here
    };

    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          {Object.keys(mealTimes).map(mealTime => (<th>{mealTimes[mealTime]}</th>))}
        </tr>
        {
          meals.map(meal => (
            <tr>
              <td>{`DAY ${meal.id}`}</td>
              {
                mealTimes.map(mealTime => (
                  <td>{meal[mealTime]}</td>
                ))
              }
            </tr>
          ))
        }
      </table>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Added new constant:

```
const columnKeys = Object.keys(meals[0]).filter((f) => f !== "Carb");
```

**Since you are skipping Carb in the result.**

**Table:**

```
<table>
        <tbody>
          {rowHeaders.map((header, index) => (
            <tr key={header}>
              <th>{header}</th>
              {meals.map((meal) =>
                index > 0 ? (
                  <td key={meal.id}>{meal[columnKeys[index]]}</td>
                ) : (
                  <td key={meal.id}>DAY {meal[columnKeys[index]]}</td>
                )
              )}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Working demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-bash-krmti?file=/src/App.jsx).

**Result**
[image]

Comment: thank You,a lot of time saved. And learned new stuff !