# Render data horizontal in react with 2 headers from left

Tags: reactjs

I was able to render data horizontally from [How to render data horizontally in table ( react )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904754/how-to-render-data-horizontally-in-table-react). But, now I am having an issue as need to have 2 headers from left as like this.
[image]

My current table is like this. [image]

My code:

```
render()

    {
     const rowHeadersmain4 = [
       "Zone",
       "Oven1",
       "Oven2",
       "Oven3",
      "Dried Noodle Packing Zone",
      "Dried Noodle Packing Zone",
      "Cooling Area Zone",
      "Cooling Area Zone"
      ];

const rowHeaders4 = 
[
  "Type",
  "DH%",
  "DH%",
  "DH%",
  "DH%",
  "Temp",
  "DH%",
  "Temp"
];

     return (
         <div>

              <table className='table4'>
            <tbody>
              
                  {rowHeadersmain4.map((header, index) => (

                    <tr key={header}>
                      
                      <th className='theader4'>{header}</th>

                      {rowHeaders4.map((header) => (
                        <tr key={header}>
                      
                         <th className='theader4'>{header}</th></tr>
                      ))}
                     
                      {this.state.humid.map((value) =>
                        index > 0 ? (

                          <td className='td4' key={value.Time}>{value[tablehumid[index]]}</td>
                        ) : (
                          <th className='theader4' key={value.Time}>{value[tablehumid[index]]}</th>
                        )
                      )}
                      
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                 


              

            </tbody>
          </table>

           </div>);


   }
```

I had render both of the headers but cannot show as the table I wanted.